# Replacing Chars in Different Encoding

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, collation

I imported data into a table from a backup I was given. Now I realized that this backup was made from a database with another collation and thus I have invalid characters, such as `├í` instead of `á`.

How can I replace such characters?

I tried this, but doesn't work:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Field1 = REPLACE(Field1, '├í', 'á')
```

Also note that I don't see: `├í`, but I see the `í` preceded by an empty square.

Comment: Can you recreate the table again from the backup with the correct collation?  Or have you already added new data?  If so you may have to recreate the table from backup and then repay all the queries after it was restored (not sure how to do that - ask a sysAdmin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is it that you “don’t see ├í, but [you] see the í preceded by an empty square”?

What’s the data type of Table1.Field1? What is the contents in binary of some rows of Field1 that need to be changed? What is the collation of Field1, which you can find with

```
SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(Field1,'Collation') FROM Table1;
```

It might be as simple as changing your UPDATE statement to specify its contents in Unicode:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET
  Field1 = REPLACE(Field1, N'├í', N'á')
```

Or it might not be. If not, it would help if you posted what you get when you SELECT CAST(Field1 AS VARBINARY(40)) -- or whatever length gives the full Field1 contents. You might need to apply a collation specification in the REPLACE expression.

Comment: I had pulled the data from a MySQL table into which such data was loaded incorrectly. I asked for the original script and transformed it into T-SQL and it worked like a charm . Thank you anyways  :)